# Backbone.js view events registered but not firing

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-events

Just getting started here and cannot seem to get this very basic thing working. All my elements render as I expect. My events register in firefox in the "events" tab, but none of them seem to fire (click, mouseover, etc). I am using the following.

- backbone 0.9.2
- underscore 1.4.1
- Marionette .10.2
- require-jquery (requireJs 2.1.0) (jquery 1.8.2)

## Router

```
define([
'jquery',
'backbone',
'underscore',
'views/TodaysProgramsView',
'collections/ProgramSnippetCollection'],
function($, Backbone, _, TodaysProgramsView, ProgramSnippetCollection){
    return Backbone.Router.extend({
        initialize:function () {

            var programSnippetCollection = new ProgramSnippetCollection([
                {title:'underwater basket weaving'},
                {title:'How to win friends and influence people and stuff'}
            ]);

            this.mainView = new TodaysProgramsView({
                el : $("#todays_programs"),
                collection:programSnippetCollection
            });

            Backbone.history.start();
        },
        routes:{
            '':'home'
        },
        'home':function () {
            this.mainView.render();
        }
    });
});
```

## Collection View [TodaysProgramsView.js]

```
define([
'jquery',
'backbone',
'underscore',
'views/ProgramSnippetView'],
function($, Backbone, _, ProgramSnippetView){
    return  Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

        events: {
            "click"   : "clicked"

        },
        clicked : function(){
            alert("parent clicked")
        },

       itemView : ProgramSnippetView
    });
});
```

## Item View [ProgramSnippetView.js]

```
define([
'jquery',
'backbone',
'underscore',
'text!templates/programSnippet.html'],
function($, Backbone, _, template){
    return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({


        events: {
            "click"   : "courseClicked",
            'mouseover' : 'mousedOver'
        },

        render: function(){

            var json = this.model.toJSON();
            console.log("RENDERING SNIPPET with data", json);
            $(this.el).html( _.template(template, json) );
            return this;
        },

        courseClicked : function(){
            alert("you clicked a course, good work");
        },

        mousedOver : function(){
            console.log("Mousin!");
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: Have you tried being more explicit with the event "click #theIDoftheElement": "courseClicked" ?

Comment: At first I was thinking along the same line but `'click':'courseClicked'` should work too. The Click event would just be attached to the el so when he clicks on the view, the alert would fire me thinketh...

Comment: I have tried so many things, it just refuses to fire. Cannot understand what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much frustration and many hours of javascript tweaking, I noticed that there was a div set with a z-index to 2. This was overlaying my target and gobbling up all the events. Sigh.